# Uploading Media files from iPhone to server

Tags: iphone, web-services, rest, soap, image-uploading

I am developing an application which can upload Media files (Audio, Video, Image) to the server.  I found out a way by using PHP server code we ware able to get the image in server and store it.  I like to know what is the better way to upload a image to a server (SOAP or REST or using PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has an article on how to use [DIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188797.aspx) (Direct Internet Message Encapsulation)

IBM also has [another way of sending soap attachments](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soapatt/) that seems a little older.

Comment: I Finally did a Rest WS using Jersey and got my image uploaded.http://wikis.sun.com/display/Jersey/Main and http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/10/23/jax-rs-multipart-support-with-resteasy/

Answer (score 0):

there are two way to upload the file using soap first is using base64_decode() and base64_encode() method 
and anothere is using URL that is send by android (SOAP) php server..
code is

```
   $tmpfile1 = './ABC.wmv'; (file from location)  
   $filename1 = 'video';      
   $handle1 = fopen($tmpfile, "r");(open in read mode)                   
   $contents1 = fread($handle1, filesize($tmpfile1));
   fclose($handle1);                                 
   $profile_video   = base64_encode($contents); (and decode it)
```